# vim: gp over the paragraph

Tags: vim, paragraph

in vim I use

```
Vj..jgp
```

or

```
Vk..kgp
```

for selected a paragraph and format.
how I can selected and format more fast the paragraph ?

Comment: I always use Vapgq to do this.

Comment: @void-pointer now, I find the same solution `vapgq` ;) but with `v`

Comment: Good point, you saved me a keystroke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As El Isra suggests in the comments, you can do `gqap` instead of `vapgq` to avoid unnecessarily going to visual mode. Some other useful variants of `ap` include `aw` (select a word) `as` (select a sentence), `ab` (select a `()` block), and `aB` (select a `{}` block). There are a number of plugins that extend this functionality for HTML tags as well, so you may be interested in searching for those.

**Edit:** Changed `V` to `v`.

**Edit 2:** Changed `vgaqp` to `gqap`.

Comment: Why enter visual mode? you can type `gqap`

Comment: In case anyone is interested in what these things are called, see `:help text-objects`.  Also, I believe html tags are native now and don't need to be added via a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
gqq
```

or

```
{gq}
```